# How to see the local node's mempool?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, mempool

I'm building a few applications and am running into scaling issues.

Occasionally a lot of transactions need to be submitted, sometimes even chained, but generally it's simply splitting an incoming UTxO to multiple target wallets. This generally works fine unless the network is somewhat congested which results in outgoing transactions "hanging around" in the local mempool for a considerably longer time and UTxOs piling up.
Everything still works but it's less than optimal and can cause the service to become even more sluggish, I'd like to avoid that.

Ideally I'd be able to build some sort of scaling solution based on the nodes' current mempool size.

Unfortunately I have not found any cardano-cli command to easily view the mempool utilization which would be really helpful, maybe I missed something obvious.

So ultimately my question is:
Is there a way to easily view the mempool utilization?

Comment: Ogmios might help for this: https://ogmios.dev/mini-protocols/local-tx-monitor/

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, [you need to use Ogmios](https://ogmios.dev/api/#operation-publish-/?Local-Tx-Monitor) to see your local mempool.

Comment: Hey Marek, just curious, do you know if it's possible to aim Ogmios to look at a remote mempool?

Comment: Ogmios just connects to a Cardano node, so it is always using a "remote mempool".

Comment: Ah I just realised my mental model was funny, essentially you need to first connect/have access to a remote node to view its mempool.